# Create tar.gz file for directory but with different name

Tags: bash, tar

I can create a file `file.tar.gz` file from a directory `directory` using

```
tar -zcvf file.tar.gz directory
```

Unpacking it using

```
tar xzf file.tar.gz
```

recreates the directory `directory`. But how to create a `file.tar.gz` from the directory `directory` that creates `directory-foo` when unpacking with the same command (the unpack command needs to be kept)? Renaming the directory `directory` to `directory-foo` before packing should be avoided as well as duplicating the directory.

When trying the suggested

```
OLDNAME=directory
NEWNAME=directory-foo
tar --transform='s,$OLDNAME/,$NEWNAME/,' -x -f file.tar.gz
```

I'm getting

```
tar: Option --transform=s,$OLDNAME/,$NEWNAME/, is not supported
Usage:
...
```

Comment: Take a look at GNU tar's option `--transform`.

Answer (score 2):

Tar admits a [sed expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/tar_6.html#SEC115) to modify file names. You may use `--transform` or `--xform`.

Comment: Is this possible in one step or should I just create the .tar.gz and then transform it?

Comment: Reworking example 1. that follows the link I sent, `tar --transform='s,directory/,directory-foo/,' -x -f file.tar.gz`